# How to mock/stub File.open each_line in ruby / rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

How to mock / stub this so that I can test what's going on within the each_line ?

```
File.open(file_path) do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    #do something here
  end 
end
```

Comment: what are you actually doing inside the each-line... can you just test for that?

Comment: I could, but I would prefer to find a better solution and have a a more thorough test.

Comment: I think you're testing implementation details when you should be testing end results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RSpec.describe "an example of mock" do
  let(:content) { StringIO.new("1\n2\n3") }

  specify do
    allow(File).to receive(:open).and_yield(content)
    # do whatever you want
  end
end
```

Comment: Just tried it, here's what I got: `Failure/Error: described_class.new.process_file("test")
<File (class)> asked to yield |[#<StringIO:0x007fd4d4097300>]| but no block was passed`

Comment: change "expect" to "allow" (see the updated example). But it looks like the production code doesn't provide block on `File.open`

Comment: just tested the next code

```ruby


RSpec.describe "an example of mock" do
  let(:content) { StringIO.new("1\n2\n3") }

  specify do
    allow(File).to receive(:open).and_yield(content)
    File.open('foo') { |f| puts f.read }
  end
end
```